# Download failure of Laravel framework due to curl error 28

Tags: php, laravel, curl, xampp, laravel-11

I'm encountering some issues while installing Laravel 11. For more details, please refer to this photo (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCAHW.png).I've attempted various solutions to resolve the problem, including modifying the php.ini file, but I am still looking for a successful solution. I'm trying to set up my first project with Laravel 11, and my goal is to complete the installation.

> Failed to download laravel/framework from dist: curl error 28 while
> downloading